# Сохранение данных в форме при перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть форма фильтра в ней предоставляется выбор характеристик шин, по нажатию на кнопку подобрать, страница перезагружается и выдает соответствующий запрос, но в форме фильтра выбранное значение не отображается, Как отобразить текст в форме выбора после перезагрузки страницы?

```
[Пример формы][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/nppkLmfr/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для отправки формы используется POST то в свойство value нужных input вписать value='".$_POST['test']."' где test - это name нужного input. Если используется GET - то $_GET['test']

update:
Если у вас используются select'ы то в месте где они генерируются необходимо дописать в тег option

```
    if ('Значение данного option'==$_POST['test']){ echo ' selected ';}
```

Пример для вашего кода. (При условии что у вас не используется генератор для этой формы, шаблонизатор или ajax)

```
<select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" name="filter_высота" size="1">
<option 
<?php if ($_POST['filter_высота']==40){
     echo ' selected '; 
     } ?>
 value="40">10.50</option>
<option>....</option>
...
</select>
```

Comment: Увы вставив ваш пример, сайт не отвечает

Comment: Забыл закрыть тег. ?> добавил после }

Comment: И возможно не стоит использовать русские буквы в name. Не уверен, что они будут корректно везде работать

Comment: Увы опять же сохранение не происходит

Comment: Скиньте свойства <form>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nppkLmfr/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nppkLmfr/3/ Вот так это должно выглядеть. jsFiddle не дружит с php, поэтому там пример не сработает. form я свой для примера добавил. Его не трогайте в своём коде

Comment: теперь же данные не вставляются в url,
изменив форму, в url подставляется только 
 ?post_type=product&
https://jsfiddle.net/nppkLmfr/9/

Comment: Значит у вас GET форма. Замените все $_POST на $_GET . <form и его свойства вообще не трогайте. Оставьте как у вас было изначально

Comment: Благодарю вроде разобрался

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае правильнее будет использовать асинхронные запросы ([AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)). Тогда вам не придется перезагружать страницу целиком, а можно будет только обновлять данные, которые пришли в запросе.

Если же у вас нет такой возможности, то можно возвращать значение фильтра в ответе на запрос.

Comment: Изначально так и было обновлялись лишь данные, но клиенту это не нравится, он желает выбрать данные потом нажать кнопку подобрать

Comment: по данными имеются в виду результаты запроса. Запрос можно отправлять так же, но не обновлять страницу целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов на чистом js. Данные формы можно сохранить в специальное хранилище браузера `localStorage`.

Например:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('filter_form');

function loadData(){
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(form.id));
  if(data != null){ // проверка на null и undefined
    form.elements.forEach(function(element){
      element.value = data[element.name];
    });
  }
}

function saveData(){
  var data = {};
  form.elements.forEach(function(element){
    data[element.name] = element.value;
  });
  localStarage.setItem(form.id, JSON.stringify(data));
}

loadData();

form.addEventListener('submit', saveData, false);
```

```html
<form id="filter_form" action="/" mthod="GET">
  <select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" name="filter_ширина" size="1">
    <option value="">Все</option>
    <option value="63">31</option>
    <option value="64">32</option>
    <option value="65">33</option>
    <option value="66">34</option>
    <option value="45">165</option>
    <option value="46">175</option>
    <option value="47">185</option>
    <option value="48">195</option>
    <option value="49">205</option>
    <option value="50">215</option>
    <option value="51">225</option>
    <option value="52">235</option>
    <option value="53">245</option>
    <option value="54">255</option>
    <option value="55">265</option>
    <option value="56">275</option>
    <option value="57">285</option>
    <option value="58">295</option>
    <option value="68">315</option>
  </select>
  <div class="vis">
    <div class="name">Высота</div>
    <select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" name="filter_высота" size="1">
      <option value="">Все</option>
      <option value="40">10.50</option>
      <option value="41">11.50</option>
      <option value="42">12.50</option>
      <option value="43">35</option>
      <option value="75">40</option>
      <option value="37">45</option>
      <option value="38">50</option>
      <option value="36">55</option>
      <option value="62">60</option>
      <option value="34">65</option>
      <option value="35">70</option>
      <option value="39">75</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="prof">
    <div class="name">Профиль</div>
    <select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" name="filter_диаметр" size="1">
      <option value="">Все</option>
      <option value="21">R13</option>
      <option value="22">R14</option>
      <option value="23">R15</option>
      <option value="24">R16</option>
      <option value="25">R17</option>
      <option value="26">R18</option>
      <option value="27">R19</option>
      <option value="28">R20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="sez">
    <div class="name">Сезон</div>

    <select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" class="bu" name="filter_cезон" size="1">
      <option value="">Все</option>
      <option value="19">Лето</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="bre">
    <div class="name">Бренд</div>

    <select class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btnfull btn-warning" name="filter_бренд" size="1">
      <option value="">Все</option>
      <option value="61">BFGoodrich</option>
      <option value="69">Michelin</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-warning pf-black" id="bu" type="submit" value="Подобрать" />
</form>
```

К сожалению здесь данный код запустить не удастся, поскольку песочница не работает с `localStorage` в целях безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

Отличная возможность сохранить данные, введённые в форму - через sessionStorage. Вот вполне достойная статья на эту тему:
https://blog.lisogorsky.ru/session-storage-save-data
Суть в следующем: при изменении содержимого любого input, записываем в Storage данные: 
 sessionStorage["key"] = "value";
 
При первоначальной загрузке страницы проверяем, есть ли в Storage эти данные. Если есть - значит они были введены и как раз был случай перезагрузки страницы. Извлекаем данные, проходя поля формы через forEach(e): 
window.sessionStorage.getItem(e.name, e.value);